# Passage Time Distributions for Poisson processes.

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, reference-request

Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a standard Poisson process with intensity $\mu$.  Let $\tau_b = \inf ( t>0 : X_t= at + b)$, where $a>0$ and $b<0$, and let $\sigma = \inf (t>0 : X_t \geq at)$.  Is there any reference for the distributions of $\tau_b$ and $\sigma$, as well as computing $P(\tau_b < \sigma)$?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $N_t$ ?


Comment: Sorry, it's fixed.

Comment: You should consider the process $Y_t=X_t-at$, which is still a Lévy process, because then it is just first passage time, and you should find many references.